# Odd alignment/margins/spacing with ng-repeat and inline-block divs

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs and web development is already not my forte, but I did search for an answer to this issue and can't find anything.
I am using ng-repeat on a div displayed as inline-block. I'm getting weird top and bottom spacing. I have a screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt2jw4cyv609t5q/screenshot.png.

Here is the base html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Knock Admin V1.0</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/ng/admin/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/ng/admin/css/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="admin">
    <div id="sidebar">
        Welcome
        <br><a href="/admin/logout">Logout</a>
    </div>

    <div id="view">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the view template:

```
<h3>My Locations</h3>
<label for="filter">Filter:</label><input type="text" id="filter" ng-model="filter.input" />

<div id="locationCardCollection">
    <div class="locationCard" ng-repeat="loc in locations | filter:filter.input" >
        {{ loc.chain.name }} - {{ loc.name }} <br>
        {{ loc.message }}
    </div>
</div>
```

And lastly, the CSS:

```
body, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
}

#view {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #555555;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.locationCard {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 1px #404040;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 1px #404040;
}

div.locationCard.hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

I'm not doing anything tricky with formatting in the angular app code, so I'll leave that out unless otherwise requested. Can someone give me a hand here?

Thanks!

Comment: if you set up a plnkr.co or a jsfiddle.net page with sample code that reproduces the problem, I can take a look.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing that. It seems that if I take away the {{ loc.message }} content in the divs, the problem goes away. Could it be an issue with the content extending beyond the div boundaries?

Comment: what happens if you add `overflow: hidden` to `locationCard` class?

Comment: adding overflow:hidden seems to fix it. It is odd though, since the content seemed to word wrap just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Added `overflow: hidden` to locationCard CSS.